# Formatting a string properly

Tags: c#, string, formatting, display

I have a string which I would like to format in the style of a table. Currently it outputs all the data but not in proper columns / rows. I would like it so that they line up and are not overlapping. Any help on what to do? Thanks

Code that returns values:

```
 public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format($"{DayValues}|{MonthValues}|{YearValues}|{TimeValues}|{TimestampValues}|{RegionValues}|{DepthValues}|{LatitudeValues}|{LongitudeValues}|{MagnitudeValues}|{IrisValues}");
        }
```

Example of output:

```
10|January |2014|07:20:46|1389338446|TURKEY|10.300|39.460|27.950|4.000|4371306
31|December |2013|15:06:14|1388502374|CRETE|26.500|34.390|25.310|4.200|4370886
29|December |2013|06:54:59|1388300099|NORTHWESTERN BALKAN REGION|10.000|43.100|17.190|4.700|4370801
28|December |2013|18:55:03|1388256903|CYPRUS REGION|46.900|35.670|31.350|4.500|4370887
```

Comment: You don't need String.Format if you are using $"".

Comment: The "return" returns it to my main in which it is written out. Is that what needs to be edited?

Comment: No, you can remove String.Format( and the closing ) -->
return $"{DayValues}|{MonthValues}|{YearValues}|{TimeValues}|{TimestampValues}|{RegionValues}|{DepthValues}|{LatitudeValues}|{LongitudeValues}|{MagnitudeValues}|{IrisValues}";

Comment: and then do what?

Comment: It was just a sidenote. To answer your question, you can use PadRight to fill the column (with spaces) to the desired length. For RegionValues you'll need to take the max length, or choose a length to truncate the column.

Comment: Can I center the values?

Comment: If you want to center something, you need to do the calculation for the padding yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want you need to pad the data to a maximum size, something like this:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{DayValues.ToString().PadRight(2, ' ')}|{MonthValues.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ')}|{YearValues.ToString().PadRight(4, ' ')}|{TimeValues.ToString().PadRight(8, ' ')}|{TimestampValues.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ')}|{RegionValues.ToString().PadRight(40, ' ')}|{DepthValues.ToString().PadRight(6, ' ')}|{LatitudeValues.ToString().PadRight(6, ' ')}|{LongitudeValues.ToString().PadRight(6, ' ')}|{MagnitudeValues.ToString().PadRight(6, ' ')}|{IrisValues.ToString().PadRight(6, ' ')}";
    }
```

I've left-aligned all the data but you can change the alignment using `PadLeft` instead of `PadRight`. Also, you need to adjust the column size (the pad length) to the maximum expected size for each value.

Comment: Thanks Man. Much appreciated

Comment: This is definitely the long way to do it.

Comment: And the short way is...?

Comment: Really nice, didn't knew that interpolated strings would allow to pad data.

Comment: @Gusman it has nothing to do with interpolated string ..... you can add any code in {}

Comment: @loneshark99 And that's what an interpolated string is... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: @loneshark99 He's not talking about code. He's talking talking about the format and width section in my answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn oh I get it now , I was looking at the wrong answer . Got it , cool

Answer (score 2):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{DayValues,2}|{MonthValues,-10}|{YearValues}|{TimeValues,8}|{TimestampValues,10}|{RegionValues,-40}|{DepthValues,6:#0.000}|{LatitudeValues,6:#0.000}|{LongitudeValues,6:#0.000}|{MagnitudeValues,6:#0.000}|{IrisValues,7}";
}
```

Comment: @saraansh if you can see this, I suggest undeleting your answer. Tabs are a great solution when _combined with_ formatted padding. The use of tabs helps things align better if you copy the text and then paste it somewhere like Excel. You use a format string like in this answer so everything is at least within a tab stop of your desired width, and put a single tab for the remaining width as the delimiter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  The key to understanding why this works is interpolation is a syntactic sugar on top of String.Format and it makes sense since formatting  works that way . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-lAIORGo7ATDUKOSCbLvlOg&tduid=(f0435b35deaf6e8f1d60a080615fd854)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-lAIORGo7ATDUKOSCbLvlOg)()